# Delta of a forwards contract

Tags: futures, pricing, forward, fair-value

in university's lecture notes, from what I understand using the replication of portfolio principle to price derivates, the forward price of a contract K should be: $K = P_0(1+r)$ where $P_0$ is the spot price of the underlying and $r$ is the risk-free rate. However, with this definition, I do not see how the delta of a forwards contract = 1 (which is what many sources are claiming). Indeed, $\frac{dK}{dP_0}=1+r$ and this isn't 1 unless $r=0$. Can someone help clarify my misunderstanding of this issue? Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think your error is in confusing forward contract and forward price.

The forward **price**, with continuous interest rates, is $K=P_0e^{rT}$. It is a **fixed** parameter of your forward contract.

The forward **contract value**, on the other hand, is $V_t=P_t-Ke^{-r(T-t)}$. Its derivative w.r.t. the underlying is then indeed $dV_t/dP_t=1$.

HTH?

Comment: An example would be the gross and net treasury futures basis wrt the underlying ctd price.